# Замена фрагмента ViewPager извне

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager

Как можно заменить текущий фрагмент в `ViewPager`? Например, нужно заменить класс фрагмента, причем из другого класса, как можно это реализовать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если правильно понял ваш вопрос, это довольно легко:

Допустим, у вас есть `MyViewPagerAdapter`, адаптер вашего `ViewPager`, у которого есть функции `addFragment()` и `removeFragment()`, и который расширяет класс `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` т.к. вы работаете с фрагментами (override-функции я опускаю, пример такого адаптера можете глянуть [здесь](https://gist.github.com/ziginsider/b1f7946f2e8b827d96d17f3f73c346be)):

```
public class MyViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    Context context;
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    //пример с TabLayout, но можно и без него, конечно
    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private final ArrayList<Fragment> fragmentList = new ArrayList<>();

    public MyViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager, Context context, ViewPager viewPager,
                            TabLayout tabLayout) {
        super(manager);
        this.context = context;
        this.viewPager = viewPager;
        this.tabLayout = tabLayout;
    }

 ...

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        /*
        * добавляем фрагмент в список
        * нужно для override-функций
        * getItem() и getCount()
        */
        fragmentList.add(fragment);
        //не забываем обновить состояние ViewPager'a
        notifyDataSetChanged();
   }

   public void removeFragment(int position) {
      //удаляем tab по позиции
      removeTab(position);

      //удаляем сам фрагмент из списка и...
      Fragment fragment = fragmentList.get(position);
      fragmentList.remove(fragment);
      //удаляем экземпляр фрагмента
      destroyItem(viewPager, position, fragment);

      //не забываем обновить состояние ViewPager'a
      notifyDataSetChanged();
   }

   private void removeTab(int position) {
      if (tabLayout.getChildCount() > 0) {
         tabLayout.removeTabAt(position);
      }
  }

}
```

`destroyItem()` - метод из `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`, который удаляет экземпляр фрагмента.

Теперь просто. В любом классе каким-либо образом получаем позицию текущего фрагмента в `ViewPage`, который хотим заменить. Например как-то так:

```
int currentTabPosition = viewPager.getCurrentItem();
```

Получаем адаптер `ViewPage` и вызываем:

```
adapter.removeFragment(currentTabPosition);
```

Получаем новый фрагмент:

```
MyFragment myFragment = new myFragment();
```

и добавляем его в адаптер:

```
adapter.addFragment(myFragment);
```